# Outgoing network blocked (NOT firewall), incoming connections ok

Tags: networking, server

I thought it would be a good idea to [install pihole](https://docs.pi-hole.net/main/basic-install/) on my ubuntu 18.04 server to block ads for my home network. However when I did that, all networking stopped. So I uninstalled pihole by [removing the recommended directories](https://discourse.pi-hole.net/t/uninstall-pi-hole-on-raspberry-pi/30530) on the server (and then rebooted).

So now my system has no notion of pihole, **I can SSH and VNC (GUI) into the server, but nothing can get out.**

Networking (ifconfig) output looks like this:

```
ens4: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1460
    inet 10.152.0.2  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 0.0.0.0
    inet6 fe80::4001:aaf:fe98:2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 42:01:0a:98:01:02  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 52675  bytes 4336857 (4.3 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 83573  bytes 66763505 (66.7 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I notice that the broadcast is set to 0.0.0.0, should it be set this way? Other machines on that network have it set to the same as the internal IP. [Here are my firewall (ufw) rules.](https://shaunhenderson.com/ufw.txt) *That link is actually the server thats having this problem* :)

Output of `/etc/resolv.conf` is:

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search google.internal
```

One other thing to note is that the output of /etc/network/interfaces is:

```
# ifupdown has been replaced by netplan(5) on this system.  See
# /etc/netplan for current configuration.
# To re-enable ifupdown on this system, you can run:
#    sudo apt install ifupdown
```

*(not sure if thats relevant or not)*

Comment: Also, the server is a Google Compute VM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Editing `/etc/resolv.conf` is only a short term solution, it is NOT persistent. The solution is to edit `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml` and paste the following:

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens4:
            dhcp4: true
            nameservers:
                addresses: [1.1.1.1, 8.8.8.8]
            set-name: ens4
```

Make sure you use 4 spaces, not tabs when editing this YAML file.
Then run `sudo netplan apply` to save changes.

Sources: [ricmedia](https://www.ricmedia.com/set-custom-dns-servers-on-ubuntu-18-or-20/#:%7E:text=Set%20custom%20DNS%20using%20Netplan%20and%20networkd,-Using%20this%20method&text=1.-,Open%20File%20Manager%20and%20navigate%20to%20%2Fetc%2Fnetplan%20%2C%20right,Enter%20sudo%20nano%20%5Bfilename%5D.) and [linuxize](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-set-dns-nameservers-on-ubuntu-18-04/)